# Query over text column takes ages to run

Tags: sql-server, performance, query-performance

I'm not used to querying text columns with a large amount of data as I've always used `NVARCHAR(MAX)` and `VARCHAR(MAX)` but this is not my Database that I'm querying.

`myTable` has 305,000 rows.

`myDescriptionField` is a text column and allows nulls & has loads of data in it.

When I run the following query, it returns a row instantly.

```
SELECT TOP 1 userid
FROM myTable 
WHERE ISNULL(userID,0) > 0 
AND TRIM(SUBSTRING(myDescriptionField,1,1)) is not null
```

However, when I add this line to the where clause, the query just sits for over a minute (not sure how long it actually takes to finish as I always end up stopping the execution).

```
AND myDescriptionField NOT LIKE ''
```

I thought it might be because I'm forced to do a not like as it's a text column and also that it may be where a lot of rows have blanks or null so I tried different combinations of the following :-

```
AND ISNULL(TRIM(SUBSTRING(myDescriptionField,1,1)),'') <> ''
```

None of this worked.

So now a quick explanation as to what I need to achieve :-

I just need to find out if at least one row has data in the column `myDescriptionField` and if so, I can move on to the next table.

Is there a quick way of returning just one row once it's hit one?

Comment: Can you use `LEN`?  - `where len(TRIM(SUBSTRING(myDescriptionField,1,1))) > 0`

Comment: Tried LEN > 0 but still no joy.

Comment: I can't alter the table as it's not my database.

Comment: Nope. Still no good. Also, isn't my SUBSTRING basically converting it to VARCHAR anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use DATALENGTH?

```
SELECT TOP 1
    userID
FROM
    myTable 
WHERE
    DATALENGTH(myDescriptionField) >= 1
```

Comment: This could be the answer. Thanks. I'll just run some test and let you know if it's solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you added another predicate, or if you changed the existing one, but you could try like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 userid
FROM myTable 
WHERE ISNULL(userID,0) > 0 
  AND NULLIF(SUBSTRING(myDescriptionField,1,1),'') is not null;
```

Comment: Yes. I did try this but of course it doesn't work because it's a Text field and it returns the following error :- The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: Totally agree with you. I only added the Trim bit out of desperation and after reading someone else's suggestion on the net. However, taking that out has no affect on the performance.

Comment: I see, so you are using substring to cast text to varchar? I'll update my answer

Comment: Exactly. As mentioned in my original question, I'm not used to handling Text fields so if there's a better way of doing this I'd be interested. Thanks for your help so far by the way. Also, the substring was an attempt to look at less data.

Comment: Still not working unfortunately.